# How can I efficiently and idiomatically filter rows of PandasDF based on multiple StringMethods on a single column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame `df` with many columns, of which one is:

```
col
---
abc:kk__LL-z12-1234-5678-kk__z
def:kk_A_LL-z12-1234-5678-kk_ss_z
abc:kk_AAA_LL-z12-5678-5678-keek_st_z
abc:kk_AA_LL-xx-xxs-4rt-z12-2345-5678-ek__x
...
```

I am trying to fetch all records where `col` starts with `abc:` and has the first `-num-` between `'1234'` and `'2345'` (inclusive using a string search; the `-num-` parts are exactly 4 digits each).

In the case above, I'd return

```
col
---
abc:kk__LL-z12-1234-5678-kk__z
abc:kk_AA_LL-z12-2345-5678-ek__x
...
```

My current (working, I think) solution looks like:

```
df = df[df['col'].str.startswith('abc:')]
df = df[df['col'].str.extract('.*-(\d+)-(\d+)-.*')[0].ge('1234')]
df = df[df['col'].str.extract('.*-(\d+)-(\d+)-.*')[0].le('2345')]
```

What is a more idiomatic and efficient way to do this in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complex string operations are not as efficient as numeric calculations. So the following approach might be more efficient:

```
m1 = df['col'].str.startswith('abc')
m2 = pd.to_numeric(df['col'].str.split('-').str[2]).between(1234, 2345)

dfn = df[m1&m2]

                                col
0    abc:kk__LL-z12-1234-5678-kk__z
3  abc:kk_AA_LL-z12-2345-5678-ek__x
```

Comment: Thanks!!! Aah; I should've made the example a little better. There may be an indeterminate number of alphanumeric values like `-z12-x9-xx1` before the first numeric one, hence the regex group. But, your larger point about using `to_numeric` is taken.

Comment: I will, of course, `timeit`, but do you have a sense for when it is better to use `m1 & m2` instead of computing `m2` based on filtering via `m1`. In my case, `m1` should be fairly selective (< 10% of rows)

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use regexp and apply function. I find it easier to play with regexp in a separate function than to crowd the pandas expression.

```
import pandas as pd
import re

def filter_rows(string):
    z = re.match(r"abc:.*-(\d+)-(\d+)-.*", string)

    if z:
        return 1234 <= (int(z.groups()[0])) <= 2345
    else:
        return False
```

Then use the defined function to select rows

```
df.loc[df['col'].apply(filter_rows)]
                                col
0    abc:kk__LL-z12-1234-5678-kk__z
3  abc:kk_AA_LL-z12-2345-5678-ek__x
```

Answer (score 1):

Another play on regex :

```
 #string starts with abc,greedy search, 
 #then look for either 1234, or 2345,   
#search on for 4 digit number and whatever else after

 pattern = r'(^abc.*(?<=1234-|2345-)\d{4}.*)'

 df.col.str.extract(pattern).dropna()

                          0
0   abc:kk__LL-z12-1234-5678-kk__z
3   abc:kk_AA_LL-z12-2345-5678-ek__x
```